# Javascript Form creation is auto calling submit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I dynamically create a form, but Func() is being called on page load, instead of on click

```
                    var addrow_f = document.createElement("form");
                    addrow_f.setAttribute('method',"post");
                    addrow_f.setAttribute('action',Func());

                    var submitelement = document.createElement('input');
                    submitelement.setAttribute("type", "submit");
                    submitelement.setAttribute("name", "dsubmit");
                    submitelement.setAttribute("value", "Submit");
                    AddChild(addrow_f, submitelement);

                    AddChild(addrow_masterContainer, addrow_f);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `action` attribute just indicates to what target the form request shall be send to.

And: Since you pass the parameter with parenthesis `()` it will be executed immediately. If you want to pass functions as callbacks, you have to do this without parenthesis.

If you want to react on events, you have to add **event listener** like `click` on an element. So you probably want to add an click event on the submit button.

Therefore it exists a function called `addEventListener` available for elements. You can use it like this: `submitelement.addEventListener("click", Func);`

Comment: works great - makes sense as well, thank you for explanation